# UITextField custom underline in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have a question about making an underline on UITextField.
I am trying to make an underline with bar on each end as shown below.

[image]

I tried the following and got this one. There is no bar on the right end.

[image]

```
extension UITextField {
func underline() {
    let borderWidth = CGFloat(1.0)
    let endBorderHeight = CGFloat(10.0)

    let bottom = CALayer()
    bottom.frame = CGRect(
        x: 1,
        y: self.frame.height - borderWidth,
        width: self.frame.width - 2,
        height: borderWidth)

    bottom.borderWidth = borderWidth
    bottom.borderColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor

    let leftEndBorder = CALayer()
    leftEndBorder.frame = CGRect(
        x: 0,
        y: self.frame.height - endBorderHeight,
        width: borderWidth,
        height: endBorderHeight)
    leftEndBorder.borderWidth = borderWidth
    leftEndBorder.borderColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor

    print(bottom.frame.width)
    let rightEndBorder = CALayer()
    rightEndBorder.frame = CGRect(
        x: self.frame.width - 1,
        y: self.frame.height - endBorderHeight,
        width: borderWidth,
        height: endBorderHeight)

    rightEndBorder.borderWidth = borderWidth
    rightEndBorder.borderColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor

    self.layer.addSublayer(leftEndBorder)
    self.layer.addSublayer(bottom)
    self.layer.addSublayer(rightEndBorder)
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```

I could make the bar on left side but having trouble making the right side because of the wrong x position of the **rightEndBorder** probably?

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong??

----- edit

I tried to set the x-position of the rightEndBorder to 200 and it gave me the following.

[image]

But if I tried to set it to 300, I don't see it anymore.

----- edit

Checked if the entire textfield was shown on the screen.

[image]

----- edit

It was that the leading and trailing constraints that changed the width of the textField I guess.

[image]

----- Solution

The problem was that I had leading and trailing constraints on the textField and those constraints changed the width after the unline was inserted. After searching google, I figured that I had to make the underline after the constraints were applied which is in the function **viewDidLayoutSubviews()**.

Comment: Are you changing the textField width after running this code?

Comment: @IanMoses I guess not if the constraints set on the storyboard does not change its width.. I have made textfield on storyboard and just adding the underline on viewDidLoad().

Comment: Can you print your  textfield and textfield rightEndBorder x-origins after initialized. What are these values?

Comment: @IanMoses I printed them out by doing "frame.origin.x" and the rightEndBorder give 513 and the textfield itself gives 8.

Comment: I apologize, could you also print your textField width.

Comment: @IanMoses I have tried to set x position of the rightEndBorder to 200 and it worked but with wrong position. But I could see it.

Comment: @IanMoses I printed it with "frame.width" and it gives me 514.

Comment: @IanMoses Please, look at my edit.

Comment: Is the updated picture showing the entire textfield frame?

Comment: If so, either your view is getting cut off or the right end border is being shifted because it is well past half along the bottom border line.

Comment: @IanMoses I think the entire textField is being displayed on the screen. I tried to make it smaller. Do you see any mistake I made on the code??

Comment: No, code itself looks good.

Comment: @IanMoses Alright, I guess I have to spend more time on this then. It seems like the size problem as you have said because I tried with x = 200 and it was visible but if I try with x = 300, it is gone and textField.width = 514. Thanks a lot. If you can write what you think as an answer, I will accept it. Please do that below.

Comment: @IanMoses See my last edit Ian. I have leading and trailing space constraint on the textfield and I think it changed the size after I added those layers. Lol Thanks a lot for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-typing from comments section as an answer.

The problem seems to be either that the view is getting cut off (thus you will not see the right border) or the right end border is being shifted farther right after setting. Reason for suspecting this is from your picture where the right border is placed at x = 200 because it is well past half along the bottom border line but should be only be 40% of the way along the line.

**Update:**

The correct answer to this question was the constraints imposed caused the textfield width to change.

Comment: No problem, happy to help.